# Order of SQL Server statements execution

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL server 2008 R2, windows 7 OS.

Within the server, I have a table `con1` which was created by following SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[con1](
    [digit_str] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In the `con1` table, I have these values:

```
 digit_str
----------------
    1
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    1.
```

I did executed following SQL statement against the database:

```
SELECT t1.digit FROM
(
select CAST(digit_str as int) as digit from con1 where RIGHT(digit_str,1) <> '.'
) as t1
where t1.digit <> 1
```

the server given me following error message:

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1.' to data type int.*

I thought my inner SQL executed first and created a temp table `t1`, so `1.` is not included in table `t1`, then SQL parser will use `where t1.digit <> 1` to filter temp table `t1`.

But above seems not right, so any one explains execution order of above SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known "feature" of SQL Server. Don't ever assume that the WHERE clause executes before the SELECT clause.

See: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

There are actually good reasons for doing that sometimes. Consider joining two tables, with A being much smaller than B.

```
select CAST(A.col1 as int), A.col2, B.col3
from A join B ...
where ... isnumeric(A.col1) = 1
```

If you inspect the query plan generated, rightly or wrongly, SQL server will stream the data from A as the leading rows to join against B. While doing that, it knows that it only needs to pull `col2` and  `function on col1`.  It could bring `col1` through just to run the function later, or for something as trivial as CAST, SQL Server might as well transform the data during the streaming process.

One thing's for sure, this strategy does make SQL Server one little bit faster in certain queries. But on a purely logical perspective, I would call it a bug.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to known,i am guessing, mssql optimizer turned my sql statement to "select CAST(digit_str as int) as digit from con1 where RIGHT(digit_str,1) <> '.' and digit_str <> 1", so it causing an error.

Comment: Thanks that is what I also facing. Also could you update the link as it is invalid now?

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain the behavior, but the following would get you what you want:

```
SELECT t1.digit FROM
(
select CAST(digit_str as int) as digit 
  from con1 
 where RIGHT(digit_str,1) <> '.' 
   AND digit_str <> '1'
) as t1
```

I'm not sure why the final *where* clause is causing that conversion to be executed since it looks to me like it should be already filtered out of the result set of t1.